# Append Object from one Object Array to Another Object Array

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I have two Object arrays. "ID" from array 1 corresponds to the same as "media_id" in array 2  I need to add the "album_ids" of array 2 to array 1.

Object 1;

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2482 [post_author] => 6 [post_date] => 2014-07-31 07:59:26)  [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2483 [post_author] => 6 [post_date] => 2014-07-31 07:59:28)`

Object 2=

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [album_id] => 52 [media_id] => 2482 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [album_id] => 92 [media_id] => 2483 )`

I need the end result to be:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2482 [post_author] => 6 [post_date] => 2014-07-31 07:59:26 [album_id] => 52)  [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2483 [post_author] => 6 [post_date] => 2014-07-31 07:59:28 [album_id] => 92)`

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: PHP works better with arrays rather than objects. You can cast 'stdClass' objects directly to arrays. You can then use the many 'array_*' functions. It will help to answer your question if you would reformat you 'data' so that it is easier to compare when reading it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I reformatted the code to help make things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, lets suppose you have two arrays of objects - array1 and array2.

aarry1 = Array( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2482 [post_author] => 6 [post_date] => 2014-07-31 07:59:26) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2483 [post_author] => 6 [post_date] => 2014-07-31 07:59:28)

array2= Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [album_id] => 52 [media_id] => 2482 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [album_id] => 92 [media_id] => 2483 )

Now try out this code.

```
$albumids = array();
foreach ( $array2 as $key => $val) {
 $albumids[$val->media_id] = $val->album_id;
}

if(!empty($albumids)) {
 foreach ( $array1 as $key => $val) {
  if(isset($albumids[$val->ID])) {
    $val->album_id = $albumids[$val->ID];
  }
 }
}

print_r($array1);
```

You would get the expected result

Edit: I had to correct the following line from:
$val->albumid = $albumids[$val->id];
to
$val->album_id = $albumids[$val->ID];

Comment: This answer appears close but it's output makes all of the  [album_id] => empty.

Comment: I made a slight typo change in your line:  $val->albumid = $albumids[$val->id];  to read  $val->album_id = $albumids[$val->ID]; and it works perfectly thank you!